# Simply connected and homotopic

Tags: complex-analysis

In complex plane, if $C$ is a closed curve that is homotopic to a point, and $C$ is the boundary of a domain $E$, is $E$ simply connected?

Comment: You need to clarify few things in your question: 1. Homotopic to a point in which space? (In the plane every loop is homotopic to a point!) 2. What do you mean by "bounds a domain"? For instance, does unit circle bound the complement to the closed unit disk? 3. Is the curve supposed to be simple? 4. Is the domain assumed to be connected?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to assume that $C$ is a *simple* closed curve. Otherwise, take a long skinny ellipse (a "sausage") and bend it until the two ends just touch, like your thumb touching your forefinger when you use them to make a circle. There's clearly a curve that bounds the sausage (even after the ends touch at a single point), and this curve is clearly contractible within the sausage shape, but the sausage shape (assuming it includes the boundary) is not contractible -- it has $\pi_1 = \mathbb Z$.

Even with the simple-closed-curve assumption I'm not entirely convinced the statement is true, but I suspect that it is.

Comment: >the sausage shape (assuming it includes the boundary) is not contractible<        Do you mean the sausage to be $E$? Well $E$ is supposed to be a domain so must be open.

Comment: I didn't realize that in the context of complex variables, "domain" always meant "open." I probably once know that, a long time ago. Anyhow, point taken.

Answer (score 0):

I have to rewrite the whole what I said:

I think you need some conditions on $C$ and $E$ to avoid pathology and to say something useful.
The conditions that come to my mind include:

1) $E$ is path-connected, (since $E$ is a domain, it is open and connected but I don't think they are strong enough to prevent pathological phenomena to take place.)

2) the pair ($E, C$) is *reasonably tame*, for example every point of $C$ has a neighbourhood in $E \cup C$ which is homeomorphic to $(-1, 1) \times [0, 1)$  where (0, 0) corresponds to the point,

3) the homotopy of $C$ to a point *occurs inside* $E$.

Of course you may need more.

Comment: shrink to what point?

Comment: You wrote "C is a closed curve that is homotopic to a point", didn't you?

Comment: On second thought if you meant, by `$C$ is homotopic to a point', that $C$ is shrinkable to a point of $E$ inside $E$,
then that homotopy can be used to define a contraction of $E$ to the point inside $E$, thus $E$ is simply connected.

Comment: The quick way I see  to use the homotopy to define a contraction would be something like "For each point $P$, find the first moment $H(s_0, t)$ where $H(s_0, t) = P$, for some $t$, and then let $P$ follow the path $H([s_0, 1], t)$." But that assumes that there is such a first moment, and that $(s_0, t)$ depends nicely on $P$. I see lots of proving left to do. Or did you have something else in mind that's simpler?

Comment: >I see lots of proving left to do.<



I quite agree. Besides, as I rewrote, we need many postulates to bypass pathology.
So, this problem is not so easy as it appears.